# Calling a function from a template using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm very new to Django and there's something I'm trying to do that I don't seem to understand how. Right now I have elements of the page show/hide using javascript onclick. What I'm showing includes a dropdown box. What I would like to do is to call a python client side function I wrote, passing the choice and thus making changes to the database. The function is written and I have the frontend working but I don't understand how to take the submit button and get the javascript to not only show/hide elements but end up calling this function.

I don't want the page to refresh which my research so far leads me to believe I need to use AJAX and some sort of POST. Not really sure about that. I've got no experience with this kind of thing. I was wondering if I was on the right track or somewhere that might help me get there/a guide of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, you will need to use AJAX. Here is quick example:

template.html

```
<button type="button" id>Click Me!</button>


{% block inline_js %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click",'#button',
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { action: "delete"},
                    success: function(data){}

</script>
```

You can put your AJAX functions directly in your view. If you put nothing in your 'url' argument of your AJAX call, it will call itself (your view that called it).

views.py

```
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
#Add a AJAX request check. If it is AJAX, redirect to AJAX function
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return self.ajax(request)

#===========================================================================
# AJAX
#===========================================================================
def ajax(self, request):
    response_dict= {
        'success': True,
    }
    #Your SQL DROP code here...


    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: I ended up getting a bit of help in person and forgot about this question when it happened but spot on answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make POST request with JavaScript, and receive it on the server. The basic idea: you send data (JSON, maybe) from the client using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (if your project uses jQuery). It is in theory, I am not familiar with Django as well. But according to the docs Django can not handle AJAX by default, so it seems to be what you need: http://www.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/